# Native/universal app format or easier to install apps for elementary os, plus a few other quick questions

Tags: applications, software-installation, appcenter, development, games

Hello :) Just a few quick questions/suggestions, sorry about any grammatical mistakes, my english isn't too good but I'm learning

I love the elementary os, i'm a huge fan! Thank you for creating it

Just wondering if at some point something like AppImage or similar may be added to Elementary OS?

Maybe like some kind of plug & play native/universal app format that allows the option of quick app installation like in ios or android or windows instead of having to build the executables or install from the repositories. Some way to make it possible to just click on a button in an app store to purchase & it installs right away

It could potentially open the door for an app store for elementary os & drive more revenue for you. I'd definitely be interested in buying from your app store. If you decide to do this, i'm sure lots of other people would love such a feature too. It would give people a better alternative to just the ios or android or windows & all the issues that come with those platforms

Is the Vulkan api already built into elementary os? I'm interested in creating game apps specifically for the elementary os

Also will elementary os be coming to mobile in the future? If so, i'd be very interested & i think you could potentially kick google's, micro$haft's & apple's a$$ets all over the place

Thank you for hearing me out & for creating such an awesome os, you guys rock!

- Ayame

Answer (score 1):

AppImages can run on elementary and other major distros today. Cody Garver from the elementary team [sits on the Snap Format oversight board](http://blog.elementary.io/post/151395260651/weve-joined-the-snap-format-tob), although elementary hasn't committed to using Snaps in the AppCenter.

The next step for AppCenter is Houston, which should make it much easier to publish apps for elementary. The idea is to turn the app center into a pay-what-you-want app store. See https://github.com/elementary/houston for details on that.

Founder Daniel Foré has this to say about elementary on mobile [(full answer)](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/4s4skf/elementary_os_for_mobiles_like_ubuntu_touch/d56tefm/):

> I'd love to do mobile, but it's not something we can just jump into doing straight away.